# Change Row Color on Grouped Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, development, jquery

I am using a code that's floating around forums like this to color code a sharepoint list. However if I switch to the grouped list view the code stops working. From research, it seems that is due to a ms-gb class that is added to the grouped view. Is there a way to use my current code and just add the class information somewhere to make it work?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

        var statusColors =  {
           'My Stuff' : 'DarkSeaGreen',  
           'Blank' : '#FF7B61',
           'Test' : 'LightSteelBlue', 
           'Hello' : 'Plum', 
           'Boat' : 'YellowGreen',    
           'Mouse' : 'DarkGray' 
        };

        var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
        {
           var status = rows[i]["Color"];
           var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
           var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
           row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
        }
      }
    }); 

 });

 </script>
```

I don't know if its not finding the rows to loop through, or if its got the right row but not getting the right element to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not the simplest solution but it should work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
            OnPostRender: function (ctx) {

                var statusColors = {
                    'My Stuff': 'DarkSeaGreen',
                    'Blank': '#FF7B61',
                    'Test': 'LightSteelBlue',
                    'Hello': 'Plum',
                    'Boat': 'YellowGreen',
                    'Mouse': 'DarkGray'
                };

                var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var status = rows[i]["Color"];
                    var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                    var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                    row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
                }
            }
        });

    });

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomJS, 'INIT.js');
    function CustomJS() {
        var _ExpCollGroup = ExpCollGroup;
        ExpCollGroup = ExpCollGroup = function (groupName, imgName, evt, noAjax) {
            if (evt != null)
                g_ExpGroupNeedsState = true;
            if (document.getElementById("titl" + groupName) == null)
                return;
            var viewTable = (document.getElementById("titl" + groupName)).parentNode;

            if (viewTable == null)
                return;
            var ctxNum = groupName.substr(0, groupName.indexOf("-"));
            var ctxCur = window["ctx" + ctxNum];

            if (!Boolean(ctxCur))
                return;
            if (!ctxCur.StateInitDone)
                ctxInitItemState(ctxCur);
            if (ctxCur.SelectAllCbx == null)
                ctxCur.SelectAllCbx = getSelectAllCbxFromTable(viewTable);
            var tbodyTags = viewTable.getElementsByTagName("TBODY");
            var numElts = tbodyTags.length;
            var len = groupName.length;
            var img = document.getElementById(imgName);

            if (img == null)
                return;
            var srcPath = img.src;
            var imgSrc = img.getAttribute('src');
            var index = srcPath.lastIndexOf("/");
            var commonClusterSrcPath = GetThemedImageUrl("spcommon.png");
            var collapseImgClass = fRightToLeft ? "ms-commentcollapsertl-icon" : "ms-commentcollapse-icon";
            var collapseSpanClass = fRightToLeft ? "ms-commentcollapsertl-iconouter" : "ms-commentcollapse-iconouter";
            var expandImgClass = fRightToLeft ? "ms-commentexpandrtl-icon" : "ms-commentexpand-icon";
            var expandSpanClass = fRightToLeft ? "ms-commentexpandrtl-iconouter" : "ms-commentexpand-iconouter";
            var oldExpandSrcPath = '/_layouts/15/images/plus.gif';
            var oldCollapseSrcPath = '/_layouts/15/images/minus.gif';
            var fOpen = false;
            var displayStr;

            if (imgSrc == oldExpandSrcPath || imgSrc == commonClusterSrcPath && img.className == expandImgClass || g_ExpInitializing) {
                fOpen = true;
                displayStr = "";
                if (imgSrc == commonClusterSrcPath) {
                    img.className = collapseImgClass;
                    img.parentNode.className = collapseSpanClass;
                }
                else
                    img.src = oldCollapseSrcPath;
            }
            else {
                fOpen = false;
                displayStr = "none";
                if (imgSrc == commonClusterSrcPath) {
                    img.className = expandImgClass;
                    img.parentNode.className = expandSpanClass;
                }
                else
                    img.src = oldExpandSrcPath;
            }
            var j = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < numElts; i++) {
                var childObj = tbodyTags[i];

                if (childObj.id != null && childObj.id.length > len + 4 && groupName == (childObj.id.slice(4)).substr(0, len)) {
                    if (fOpen) {
                        index = childObj.id.indexOf("_", len + 4);
                        if (index != -1) {
                            index = childObj.id.indexOf("_", index + 1);
                            if (index != -1)
                                continue;
                        }
                    }
                    var previousDisplay = childObj.style.display;

                    childObj.style.display = displayStr;
                    var itemCount = 0;

                    if (Boolean(childObj.getAttribute("selectableRows"))) {
                        itemCount = Number(childObj.getAttribute("selectableRows"));
                        //custom logic
                       // currentGroupRows = childObj.rows;
                        //custom logic done
                    }
                    if (typeof FV4UI != "undefined" && FV4UI() && Boolean(itemCount)) {
                        if (!fOpen) {
                            if (previousDisplay != "none")
                                ctxCur.TotalListItems -= itemCount;
                            EnsureScriptParams("core.js", "DeselectCollapsedGroup", ctxCur, childObj);
                            EnsureScriptParams("core.js", "UpdateSelectAllCbx", ctxCur, true);
                        }
                        else {
                            ctxCur.TotalListItems += itemCount;
                            EnsureScriptParams("core.js", "UpdateSelectAllCbx", ctxCur, false);
                        }
                    }
                    if (fOpen && childObj.id.substr(0, 4) == "titl") {
                        var imgObj = document.getElementById("img_" + childObj.id.slice(4));
                        var imgObjSrc = imgObj.getAttribute('src');

                        if (imgObjSrc == commonClusterSrcPath) {
                            imgObj.className = expandImgClass;
                            imgObj.parentNode.className = expandSpanClass;
                        }
                        else {
                            imgObj.src = oldExpandSrcPath;
                        }
                    }
                    var groupID = "tbod" + groupName;
                    var child;

                    if (childObj.id.substr(0, groupID.length) == groupID) {
                        if (noAjax) {
                            for (j = 0; j < childObj.childNodes.length; j++) {
                                child = childObj.childNodes[j];
                                child.style.display = displayStr;
                            }
                        }
                        if (childObj.childNodes.length == 0) {
                            var nextTBody = childObj.nextSibling;

                            while (nextTBody != null) {
                                if (nextTBody.tagName == "TBODY" && nextTBody.id == "") {
                                    for (j = 0; j < nextTBody.childNodes.length; j++) {
                                        child = nextTBody.childNodes[j];
                                        child.style.display = displayStr;
                                        if (typeof FV4UI != "undefined" && FV4UI()) {
                                            HandleSingleGroupByRow(ctxCur, child, fOpen);
                                            UpdateSelectAllCbx(ctxCur, true);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                    nextTBody = nextTBody.nextSibling;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (FV4UI())
                EnsureScriptParams("core.js", "UpdateCtxLastSelectableRow", ctxCur, viewTable);
            if (!noAjax && !g_ExpGroupParseStage) {
                if (g_ExpGroupNeedsState && ExpGroupFetchWebPartID(groupName) != null && !Boolean(ctxCur.noGroupCollapse)) {
                    if (fOpen) {
                        AddGroupToCookie(groupName);
                    }
                    else {
                        RemoveGroupFromCookie(groupName);
                    }
                }
                if (fOpen) {
                    var tbody = document.getElementById("tbod" + groupName + "_");

                    if (tbody != null) {
                        var isLoaded = tbody.getAttribute("isLoaded");

                        if (isLoaded == "false") {
                            ExpGroupFetchData(groupName, evt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //custom logic

            setTimeout(
                function () {
                    //alert('custom logic')
                    var statusColors = {
                        'My Stuff': 'DarkSeaGreen',
                        'Blank': '#FF7B61',
                        'Test': 'LightSteelBlue',
                        'Hello': 'Plum',
                        'Boat': 'YellowGreen',
                        'Mouse': 'DarkGray'
                    };

                    var rows = ctxCur.ListData.Row;
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        if (rows[i]["Color"] != undefined) {
                            var status = rows[i]["Color"];
                            var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                            var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                            row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
                        }
                    }

                },
            500);

        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]